# How to translate decimal number to time in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

THrough Table Capture extension I have copied a html table from a webpage into the google spreadsheet.
In that table, there is a column in decimals for ex :

```
12.4
```

I want to change this into

```
12:40:00
```

If I normally replace `.` with `:` then it's replacing to

```
12:04:00
```

Comment: This is a time type, isn't it?

Comment: yes...It's the time type I want it to change into

Comment: And what about `12.34` **edit :** it works well.

Comment: 12.34 into 8:09:36 when I go to format->number->Time

Comment: Do you know `Google App Scripts`? Do you have numbers like `12.345` or with max 2 decimals?

Comment: I don't know Google App Scripts....
I don't have numbers like 12.345

Comment: And do you have any programing skills?

Comment: yes...somewhat..I guess..

Comment: Wouldn't you want 12.4 hours to be converted to 12:24?  `60 * 0.4 == 24`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>You should give a try with `Format` => `Number` => `Time`</del>

You should open a new script by `Tools`=> `Script Editor` and take a look at [that](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates?hl=en) which is a tutorial to *delete* row and you'll need to adapt it to change row values. You'll find all the needed doc [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

And your code may look like this :

```
for each row{
    var string = new array(2);
    //Split the string a the .
    string = row.split(".");

    // if the second part is like 4 in 12.4 you set it to 40
    if (string[1].lenght() == 1)
        string[1] += 0;

    // Set the row value to the format you like, here : 12:40:00
    row.setValue(string[0] + ":" + string[1] + ":00");
}
```

Comment: I tried with it...It's changing the whole value..I don't know why..
12.4 changed to 9:36:00..

Comment: yeah..just now I finished with some (actually quite a bit) modifications..anyway thank you...VBB..really thanx a lot..